Can't download project due to unhandled exception
Why can't I redownload a project?
I’ve tried so many times but still had the same error, I even re-install plugin mergin map and re-installed QGIS to new version, but still can't solve my problem. here is the detail about the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users/ZEPHYRUS/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Mergin\sync_dialog.py", line 150, in download_timer_tick
    download_project_finalize(self.job)

  File "C:\Users/ZEPHYRUS/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Mergin\mergin\client_pull.py", line 239, in download_project_finalize
    task.apply(job.directory, job.mp)

  File "C:\Users/ZEPHYRUS/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Mergin\mergin\client_pull.py", line 291, in apply
    mp.geodiff.make_copy_sqlite(mp.fpath(self.file_path), mp.fpath_meta(self.file_path))

  File "C:\Users/ZEPHYRUS/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Mergin\mergin\deps\pygeodiff\main.py", line 255, in make_copy_sqlite
    return self.clib.make_copy_sqlite(src, dst)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "C:\Users/ZEPHYRUS/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Mergin\mergin\deps\pygeodiff\geodifflib.py", line 440, in make_copy_sqlite
    _parse_return_code(res, "make_copy_sqlite")

  File "C:\Users/ZEPHYRUS/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Mergin\mergin\deps\pygeodiff\geodifflib.py", line 45, in _parse_return_code
    raise GeoDiffLibError(msg)

Mergin.mergin.deps.pygeodiff.geodifflib.GeoDiffLibError: make_copy_sqlite

What is wrong??
I’m still learning about QGIS and this is the first time I have had an error like that.

It looks like a know issue https://github.com/MerginMaps/qgis-plugin/issues/605.

Delete the project directory and re-download the Mergin project - Issue #284
